# Writing String.trim() in C

Tags: c, trim

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Painless way to trim leading/trailing whitespace in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/painless-way-to-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-c)
> [Trim a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656542/trim-a-string-in-c)

I was writing the String trim method in c and this is the code I came up with. I think it does the job of eliminating leading and trailing whitespaces however, I wish the code could be cleaner. Can you suggest improvements?

```
void trim(char *String)
{
int i=0;j=0;
char c,lastc;
while(String[i])
{
   c=String[i];
   if(c!=' ')
   {
     String[j]=c;
     j++;
   }
   else if(lastc!= ' ')
   {
     String[j]=c;
     j++;

   }
   lastc = c;
   i++;
}
```

Does this code look clean ??

Comment: well it only checks for the *SPACE* character. White space usually consists of checking for TAB, Carriage Return and Line Feed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/painless-way-to-trim-leadingtrailing-whitespace-in-c

Comment: Posted an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656542/trim-a-string-in-c/1431206#1431206

Comment: `else if(lastc!= ' ')` when `lastc` is never asigned to. Consider posting at  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look clean.  Assuming the first character is a space, you're using `lastc` with an undefined value.  You're leaving one space at the end (if there's a space at the end, when it's hit `c` will be a space and `lastc` won't).

You're also not terminating the string.  Assuming you fix the uninitialized `lastc` problem, you'll transform "  abc" to "abcbc", since it's not being shortened at any point.

The code also collapses multiple spaces inside the string.  This isn't what you described; is it desired behavior?

Answer (score 3):

It often makes your code more readable if you make judicious use of the standard library functions - for example, `isspace()` and `memmove()` are particularly useful here:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void trim(char *str)
{
    char *start, *end;

    /* Find first non-whitespace */
    for (start = str; *start; start++)
    {
        if (!isspace((unsigned char)start[0]))
            break;
    }

    /* Find start of last all-whitespace */
    for (end = start + strlen(start); end > start + 1; end--)
    {
        if (!isspace((unsigned char)end[-1]))
            break;
    }

    *end = 0; /* Truncate last whitespace */

    /* Shift from "start" to the beginning of the string */
    if (start > str)
        memmove(str, start, (end - start) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Do I have your permisison to use this in commercial software?

Answer (score 1):

There's several problems with that code. It only checks for space. Not tabs or newlines. You are copying the entire non-whitespace part of the string. And you are using lastc before setting it.

Here's an alternate version (compiled but not tested):

```
char *trim(char *string)
{
    char *start;
    int len = strlen(string);
    int i;

    /* Find the first non whitespace char */
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (! isspace(string[i])) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == len) {
        /* string is all whitespace */
        return NULL;
    }

    start = &string[i];

    /* Remove trailing white space */
    for (i = len; i > 0; i--) {
        if (isspace(string[i])) {
            string[i] = '\0';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return start;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems: `lastc` could be used uninitialized. And you could make use of a for loop instead of a while loop, for example. Furthermore, trim/strip functions usually replace spaces, tabs and newlines.

Here's a solution using pointers that I wrote quite a while ago:

```
void trim(char *str)
{
    char *ptr = str;
    while(*ptr == ' ' || *ptr == '\t' || *ptr == '\r' || *ptr == '\n') ++ptr;

    char *end = ptr;
    while(*end) ++end;

    if(end > ptr)
    {
        for(--end; end >= ptr && (*end == ' ' || *end == '\t' || *end == '\r' || *end == '\n'); --end);
    }

    memmove(str, ptr, end-ptr);
    str[end-ptr] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

Short, simple, clean, commented, and lightly tested.

It uses the "isspace" classification function, so you can easily change your definition of "white space" to be trimmed.

```
void trim(char* String)
{
    int dest;
    int src=0;
    int len = strlen(String);

    // Advance src to the first non-whitespace character.
    while(isspace(String[src])) src++;

    // Copy the string to the "front" of the buffer
    for(dest=0; src<len; dest++, src++) 
    {
        String[dest] = String[src];
    }

    // Working backwards, set all trailing spaces to NULL.
    for(dest=len-1; isspace(String[dest]); --dest)
    {
        String[dest] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be dangerous when strlen(String) is 0.

Comment: There is more to whitespace than the space charachter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing a character with the space character ' ', I'd use the "isspace" function, which I believe is defined in ctype.h.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about clean, but I find it hard to follow. If I needed to do this I'd initially think of it in two phases:

1. Figure out how many characters to drop from the beginning, then memmove the rest of the string (including the null terminator) to the start address. (You might not need the memmove if you are allowed to return a different start pointer, but if so you need to be very careful with memory hygiene.)
2. Figure out how many characters to drop from the (new) end and set a new null terminator there.

I might then look more closely at a one-pass solution like you seem to be trying to implement, but only if there was a speed problem.

By the way, you probably want to use `isspace()` rather than checking only for space.