# Removing spaces from a string in C

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I trim leading/trailing whitespace in a standard way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way)

I need to remove all spaces from the beginning and at the end of the string for instance if my string is

```
"     hello     world.       "
```

(without quotes), I need to print

```
"hello     world."
```

I tried something like this:

```
size_t length = strlen (str);
for (newstr = str; *newstr; newstr++, length--) {
    while (isspace (*newstr)) 
        memmove (newstr, newstr + 1, length--);
```

but it removes all spaces.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/painless-way-to-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656542/trim-a-string-in-c

Comment: See the answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/painless-way-to-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-c

Comment: Probably not a good idea using a variable called `new` if you _ever_ expect your code may be used in a C++ environment :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to memmove.  Just start at the starting point (scan until first nonspace character).  Then, work from the back and find the first non-space character.  Move ahead one and then replace with a null termination character.

```
char *s = str;
while(isspace(*s)) ++s;
char *t = str + strlen(str);
while(isspace(*--t));
*++t = '\0';
```

Answer (score 6):

Skip the spaces at the beginning with a `while(isspace(...))`, and then `memmove` the string from the position you reached to the beginning (you can also do the `memmove` work manually with the classic "trick" of the two pointers, one for read and one for write).

```
You start from

[ ][ ][H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][ ][ ][\0]
 ^

[ ][ ][H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][ ][ ][\0]
       ^ skipping the two spaces you move your pointer here

... and with a memmove you have...
[H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][ ][ ][\0]
```

Then, move your pointer at the end of the string (you can help yourself with a `strlen`), and go backwards until you find a non-space character. Set the character after it to `0`, and voilà, you just cut the spaces off the end of your string.

```
                                     v start from the end of the string
[H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][ ][ ][\0]

... move backwards until you find a non-space character...
                               v
[H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][ ][ ][\0]

.... set the character after it to 0 (i.e. '\0')

[H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][\0]

... profit!
```