# How can I trim and pass an array of strings into a function?

Tags: c, string

How can I trim a string into pieces of N numbers of characters and then pass them as an array of strings into a function?

This in a part of my program that converts binary<->hex.

I tried doing the same thing with strings but it did not work.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <String.h>

#define MAXDIGITS 8  // 8bits 


int main()
{
    int y;

    printf("Binary-Hex convertor\n");
    printf("Enter the  Binary value : ");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    int i = MAXDIGITS - 1;
    int array[MAXDIGITS];

    while(y > 0)
    {
        array[i--] = y % 10;
        y /= 10;
    }

    printf("%s", "-----------------\n");
    printf("%s", "HEX:");

    int x = array[0];
    int x1 = array[1];
    int x2 = array[2];
    int x3 = array[3];
    int x4 = array[4];
    int x5 = array[5];
    int x6 = array[6];
    int x7 = array[7];

    char buffer[50];
    char buffer2[50];
    char buffer3[50];
}
```

Comment: so smart! it is not homework. Even it was homework, why would not you share knowledge with other people?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Your question is imprecise? Try again to describe what the spec is.

Comment: What is your input? What is your expected output? What is your actual output?

Comment: If it was [tag:homework], we would not give you the answer, but the path you would take to reach the destination. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim a string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656542/trim-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just binary to hex from a string then this is much easier....

```
char *input_string = "1001010101001010";
int count = 0;
int value = 0;

while ( *input_string != '\0' )
{
    // Might be worth checking for only 0 and 1 in input string
    value <<= 1;
    value |= (int)((*input_string--) - '0');

    if ( ++count == 8 || *input_string == '\0' )
    {
        // USE value to print etc, if you want to display use 
        // the following else you could store this in an array etc.
        printf("%x ", value);
        count = 0;
        value = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to null terminate the strings, do you have a limit on this memory used.  Do you need to allocate the memory correctly etc? A bit more info would be useful

```
const char *input_string = "HELLO THIS IS SOME INPUT STRING";
int N = 4; // The number to split on

// Work out how many strings we will end up in
int number_of_strings = (strlen(input_string) + (N - 1)) / N;

// ALlow for an extra string if you want to null terminate the list
int memory_needed = ((number_of_strings + 1) * sizeof(char *)) + (number_of_strings * (N + 1));
char *buffer = malloc(memory_needed);
char **pointers = (char **)buffer;
char *string_start = (buffer + ((number_of_strings + 1) * sizeof(char *));
int count = 0;

while ( *input_string != '\0' )
{
    // Fresh string
    if ( count == 0 )
    {
        *pointers++ = string_start;
        *pointers = NULL;  // Lazy null terminate
    }

    // Copy a character
    *string_start++ = *input_string++;
    *string_start = '\0';  // Again lazy terminat     

    count++;

    if ( count == N )
    {
        count = 0;
        string_start++; // Move past the null terminated string
    }
}
```

You can then pass (char **)buffer; to a routine.  I havent actually tried this, ive been lazy in the terminating of the strings.  You could just terminate at the end of a count run and the end of the while loop.  This isnt exactly pretty code, but it should do the job.  Bit more info on the other requirements might be good.