# How to trim leftmost and rightmost whitespaces of a string using PHP?

Tags: php, string, function, whitespace

What function can I use?

Comment: trim().Sorry, I just forgot this function.

Comment: @Filburt Your [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/122616/1267661) is in C not PHP. I would use trim() like the accepted answer here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) to remove whitespace at the start and end of a string.

Answer (score 3):

left most

```
ltrim('text');
```

right most

```
rtrim('text');
```

but shortcut of above two is simply

```
trim('text');
```

Answer (score 0):

[string trim  ( string $str  [, string $charlist  ] )](https://www.php.net/trim)

This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php would be your best choice

Answer (score 0):

Checkout PHP [Trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).