# Remove Multiple Spaces Before and After Characters PHP

Tags: php

say I have a string like so

```
 Testing
```

How could I have it remove all spaces before the first letter, and all spaces after the last letter in the string.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892763/how-to-trim-leftmost-and-rightmost-whitespaces-of-a-string-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here for all string functions in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

use trim(string)

Answer (score 1):

use [trim()](http://www.php.net/trim)

Be sure to have this close by: [String functions in PHP](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
string trim  (  string $str  [,  string $charlist  ] )
```