# Trim function in C, to trim in place (without returning the string)

Tags: c, string, pointers, trim

```
char testStr[] = "          trim this           ";
char** pTestStr = &testStr;
trim(pTestStr);

int trim(char** pStr)
{
 char* str = *pStr;
 while(isspace(*str)) {
  (*pStr)++;
  str++;
 }

 if(*str == 0) {
  return 0;
 }

 char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
 while(end > str && isspace(*end))
  end--;
 *(end+1) = 0;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/painless-way-to-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char testStr[] = "          trim this           ";
char* pTestStr = &testStr[0];
trim(&pTestStr);

void trim(char* str)
{
    if(!str)
        return;

    char* ptr = str;
    int len = strlen(ptr);

    while(len-1 > 0 && isspace(ptr[len-1]))
        ptr[--len] = 0;

    while(*ptr && isspace(*ptr))
        ++ptr, --len;

    memmove(str, ptr, len + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to make `testStr` writeable:

```
char testStr[] = "          trim this           ";
```

The problem is that `char *ptr = ...` has `ptr` pointing to the actual literal string which is in read-only memory.

By using `char testStr[] = ...` you are allocating an array and having the array initialized with the same contents as the literal string.  Since this is an array, it is writable.

Comment: I get:
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char (*)[38]' to 'char **'

Comment: @user364100 - no you can't.  You'll want to change your function to `char* trim(char* pStr)` and then return the pointer to the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: I don't want that.  I want a trim function that trims in place.

Comment: @user364100 - it's still doing it in place.  The question is whether you modify the input parameter or return a new value.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to pass a pointer to the string, and move that pointer to reflect what's been trimmed off the left.

Adding the null terminator to right-trim is easy enough.

Comment: @user364100 - you can't change the place in memory an array references and you can't modify the contents of a literal string.  You could move to the heap but that brings a different set of issues.  Accept the limitations of the language and work with them.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :** updated the code based on the latest version of [zString](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString) library.

Below is my implementation for `trim`, `left-trim` and , `right-trim`functions (will be added to [zString string library](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString)).

Although the functions return `*char`, since the original string is modified, these would serve your purpose.

One could use standard library functions, such as `isspace()`, but implementations below are bare bone code, that relies on no library function.

```
/* trim */
char *zstring_trim(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    char c;
    int is_space=0;
    int in_word=0;  /* word boundary logical check */
    int index=0;    /* index of the last non-space char*/

    /* validate input */
    if (!str)
        return str;

    while ((c=*src)){
        is_space=0;

        if (c=='\t' || c=='\v' || c=='\f' || c=='\n' || c=='\r' || c==' ')
            is_space=1;

        if(is_space == 0){
         /* Found a word */
            in_word = 1;
            *dst++ = *src++;  /* make the assignment first
                               * then increment
                               */
        } else if (is_space==1 && in_word==0) {
         /* Already going through a series of white-spaces */
            in_word=0;
            ++src;
        } else if (is_space==1 && in_word==1) {
         /* End of a word, dont mind copy white spaces here */
            in_word=0;
            *dst++ = *src++;
            index = (dst-str)-1; /* location of the last char */
        }
    }

    /* terminate the string */
    *(str+index)='\0';

    return str;
}

/* right trim */
char *zstring_rtrim(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    char c;
    int is_space=0;
    int index=0;    /* index of the last non-space char */

    /* validate input */
    if (!str)
        return str;

    /* copy the string */
    while(*src){
        *dst++ = *src++;
        c = *src;

        if (c=='\t' || c=='\v' || c=='\f' || c=='\n' || c=='\r' || c==' ')
            is_space=1;
        else
            is_space=0;

        if (is_space==0 && *src)
            index = (src-str)+1;
    }

    /* terminate the string */
    *(str+index)='\0';

    return str;
}

/* left trim */
char *zstring_ltrim(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    char c;
    int index=0;    /* index of the first non-space char */

    /* validate input */
    if (!str)
        return str;

    /* skip leading white-spaces */
    while((c=*src)){ 
        if (c=='\t' || c=='\v' || c=='\f' || c=='\n' || c=='\r' || c==' '){
            ++src;
            ++index;
        } else
            break;
    }

    /* copy rest of the string */
    while(*src)
        *dst++ = *src++;

    /* terminate the string */
    *(src-index)='\0';

    return str;
}
```