# Blank char counter in C

Tags: c

I am trying to create a small function that returns the number of spaces in a Char*
variable using the C language.

Let's say I have this string :`"hello hello hello"`. I want the function to return `2`.
This is the code I have so far:

```
int blankcounter(char* pline)
{                              
  int i=0;                  
  int counter = 0;            
  while (pline[i] != '\0')       
  {                               
    if (pline[i++] ==' ')
      counter++;
  }
  return counter;
}
```

the source that i am reading from is a txt file and 1 correction that i have to add is that the code that i posted indeed works but got 1 downside: if for example i want to read : "hello whats up "`i want my function to be able to return 2 but it returns 3 because of the space that appears just after the word`up do u have any suggestion for me so it will return 2 ?

Comment: Works for me.  It will only check for literal spaces.  You could use `isspace` to be more general.

Comment: for some reason it doesnt work for me ... the counter stays on 0
even tho i got some spaces

Comment: How are you determining that? You should use `const char*` to point at strings. Also, `counter`, `i`, and the return value should all be unsigned types (negative values don't make sense). And you might turn the `while` into a `for`, though that's arguably just a preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you would not want to count leading spaces too " hello whats up" should return 2 as well right?

I can propose 2 solutions. First is to trim all spaces before you start counting them [How do I trim leading/trailing whitespace in a standard way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/painless-way-to-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-c).

The second is to adjust the start and end point of your loop to the first and last non-space characters and then perform the count:

```
int start=0;  
int end = strlen(pline);  
int i=0;  
while (pline[i++]==' ') start++;  
i=end-1;  
while (pline[i--]==' '&& i >= 0) end--;  
for (i=start; i<end; i++) { your count procedure}
```

Comment: the source that i am reading from is a txt file 
and 1 correction that i have to add is that the code that i posted indeed works but got 1 downside:
if for example i want to read : `"hello whats up "`i want my function to be able to return 2 but it returns 3 because of the space that appears just after the word `up` do u have any suggestion for me so it will return 2 ?

Comment: I suspect you would not want to count leading spaces too " hello whats up" should return 2 as well right? I can propose 2 solutions. First is to trim all spaces before you start counting them <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/painless-way-to-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-c>. The second is to adjust the start and end point of your loop to the first and last non-space characters and then perform the count: int start=0;int end = strlen(pline); int i=0; while (pline[i++]==' ') start++; and the same way going down from the end of the string to adjust the "end".

Answer (score 0):

Question: Blank char counter in C?

Answer: Yes.

Comment: and yes the blank char is in c