# C, reading simple formula strings from input

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

for a homework, we need to input simple formulas (such as `3*2`, `4+10`, `50/16`, etc.) and calculate the result (and rest) using only addition, subtraction, and bit shifting. Anyway, I could use three subsequent input reading, however I thought I'd try getting the formula in one pass using `fgets()` and `sscanf()`. Here is what I have :

```
int *v;  // value (left side)
int *m;  // modifier (right side)
char *o; // operant

int res = sscanf(buffer,"%d%s%d",v,o,m);
```

But naturally, this does not work, because `o` gets all the remaining portion of the string, leaving `m` with nothing (`m` equals whatever value is where and when it is declared)

Now, what would be the proper way to accomplish this?

**NOTE** : I'm using [a trim function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/painless-way-to-trim-leadingtrailing-whitespace-in-c) to trim extra spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `%c` instead of `%s`.  If the operator is always a single character, and there are no spaces between the operator and the operands, this should work.

By the way, are you initializing `v`, `m`, and `o` to actually point to something?  It would be much better to do this:

```
int v;
int m
char o;

int res = sscanf(buffer, "%d%c%d", &v, &o, &m);
```

As my "Intro to Programming in C" professor used to say: "C is dangerous.  Practice safe C!".

Comment: I omitted how the initial variables are declared (they are not pointers initially, but I pass their pointer to a function where `sscanf()` sits)

Comment: Ok.  Just checking. This is such an common mistake, that I had to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `%[-+*/]` (with your set of operators) to ensure, that operator string gets only operator characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have extraneous spaces and operators are all one character long, you could use `%c` to fill in `o`.

Comment: I could... that would be an easy and quick fix so I don't have to write a whole formula parser :P