# Is there a way for std::map to "edit" values like a predicate for the key?

Tags: c++, predicate, stdmap

I am wondering if it is possible to create something like a predicate for a std::map for all of its values so I don't have to edit the values before I insert them into the map.

What I would like is something like this:

```
mymap["username"] = " Marlon "; // notice the space on both sides of my name
assert(mymap["username"] == "Marlon"); // no more whitespace
```

The context is I am creating a std::map for a .ini file and **I would like it to automatically remove leading/trailing whitespace from the values when I want to retrieve them**. I've already created a predicate to ignore casing and whitespace from the key so I want to know if it is possible to do the same for the value.

Comment: Trim the values either when you insert or retrieve them? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/painless-way-to-trim-leadingtrailing-whitespace-in-c

Comment: Not to be rude, but for the sake of the question I am asking please read what I wrote in bold.

Comment: Why do you want this?  Is it so bad to modify them before insertion?

Comment: To know if it is possible in C++. Isn't it good to know the capabilities of a language? :D

Comment: C++ can do a lot of things.  It doesn't make it a good idea.  (As to ascertaining a language's capabilities, I'd say knowing it's Turing complete should be enough...  :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a wrapper class that wraps `std::string` and

1. is implicitly constructible from `std::string`
2. implements a conversion operator from `std::string`.

You can edit the value on the fly in either of these functions. You `std::map` can hen have the wrapper as a key.

With that said, it's still better being a little more explicit, than clever, and have a separate INI class with its own get/set interface.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must follow the overloading principles to achieve the desired objective,
Try this option,

```
//map<string,string> testMap; Old Map definition
tMap testMap;
```

Where,

```
class tMap
{
        public:

                map<mystring,string> _tMap;

                mystring& operator [] (const char *index)
                {
                        return _tMap[index];
                }

};
```

mystring again is a class which can be overloaded for '==' operator for trimming.
I know maps can be implemented as a class (Wrapper) and then used to achieve the desired result. May be a bit more effort would solve this problem.