# Is it safe to call the functions from <cctype> with char arguments?

Tags: c++, c, character, undefined-behavior, language-lawyer

The C programming language says that the functions from `<ctype.h>` follow a common requirement:

ISO C99, 7.4p1:

> In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

This means that the following code is unsafe:

```
int upper(const char *s, size_t index) {
  return toupper(s[index]);
}
```

If this code is executed on an implementation where `char` has the same value space as `signed char` and there is a character with a negative value in the string, this code invokes *undefined behavior*. The correct version is:

```
int upper(const char *s, size_t index) {
  return toupper((unsigned char) s[index]);
}
```

Nevertheless I see many examples in C++ that don't care about this possibility of undefined behavior. So is there anything in the C++ standard that guarantees that the above code will not lead to undefined behavior, or are all the examples wrong?

[Additional Keywords: ctype cctype isalnum isalpha isblank iscntrl isdigit isgraph islowwer isprint ispunct isspace isupper isxdigit tolower]

Comment: You're asking about C++ but quoting from C99 ?

Comment: Oh well, C++98 was before C99. Nevertheless, the text from C90 is almost the same, and C++98 borrows its standard library from C90, so yes, I'm quoting from the C standard intentionally.

Comment: the signedness of char is compiler-specific. although I doubt it, maybe some of those "wrong" example projects force the compiler to treat char as unsigned.

Comment: @cnicutar The C++98 standard contained details about <cctype>. Following C++ standards removed the section entirely in favor of explicitly stating in **[cctype.syn]** that one should refer to ISO C section 7.4 for definitions, where ISO C is the latest C standard at the time of writing (i.e. C99 in all cases). The quote in the OP is therefore the correct (and only) quote, as per all C++ standards in the past 20 years. This was also the case 10 years ago when the OP was posted. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, the Solaris Studio compilers (using `stlport4`) are one such compiler suite that produce an unexpected result here. Compiling and running this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    char ch = '\xa1'; // '¡' in latin-1 locales + UTF-8
    printf("is whitespace: %i\n", std::isspace(ch));
    return 0;
}
```

gives me:

```
kevin@solaris:~/scratch
$ CC -library=stlport4 whitespace.cpp && ./a.out 
is whitespace: 8
```

For reference:

```
$ CC -V
CC: Studio 12.5 Sun C++ 5.14 SunOS_i386 2016/05/31
```

Of course, this behavior is as documented in the C++ standard, but it's definitely surprising.

---

EDIT: Since it was pointed out that the above version contained undefined behavior in the attempt to assign `char ch = '\xa1'` due to integer overflow, here's a version that avoids that and still retains the same output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    char ch = -95;
    printf("is whitespace: %i\n", std::isspace(ch));
    return 0;
}
```

And that does still print 8 on my Solaris VM:

```
kevin@solaris:~/scratch
$ CC -library=stlport4 whitespace.cpp && ./a.out 
is whitespace: 8
```

---

EDIT 2: And here's a program that might otherwise look sane but gives an unexpected result due to UB in the use of `std::isspace()`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

static int count_whitespace(const char* str, int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (std::isspace(str[i]))  // oops!
            count += 1;
    return count;
}

int main() {
    const char* batman = "I am batman\xa1";
    int n = std::strlen(batman);
    std::printf("%i\n", count_whitespace(batman, n));
    return 0;
}
```

And, on my Solaris machine:

```
kevin@solaris:~/scratch
$ CC whitespace.cpp && ./a.out
3
```

Note that depending on how you permute this program, you'll probably get the expected result of two whitespace characters; that is, there is almost certainly some compiler optimization kicking in that takes advantage of this UB to give you the wrong result faster.

You could imagine this biting you in the face if you were, for example, attempting to tokenize a UTF-8 string by searching for (non-multibyte) whitespace characters in the string.  Such a program would behave correctly when casting `str[i]` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: `char` has implementation defined signedness. If it is signed and you store a value larger than 127 into it, such as 0xA1, you invoke an integer overflow, which is undefined behavior. This UB bug happens _before_ you call the ctype.h function. So this answer proves nothing except that it is unsafe to overflow signed integers. No news there. Change to unsigned char and it will work just fine.

Comment: After the edit, when you set -95 to a signed char, this gets converted to an int when passed to isspace. You get a lvalue conversion from `char` to `int`. The sign is preserved. So what this code passes to the function is 0xFFFFFFA1. This value isn't representable as unsigned char, nor as EOF, so the code invokes UB. Again the problem does not lie with the ctype.h functions, but with the programmer using the `char` type for storing integers. Why you would pass -95 to the ctype functions in a real world program, I have no idea. If you do really strange things, then strange things will happen.

Comment: The OP wasn't asking whether this was undefined behavior (we know it is). The OP was asking whether there exists an implementation that gives you a surprising result when invoking this undefined behavior. The Solaris Studio compilers happen to be one such compiler suite that give you surprising results, whereas I imagine other compilers (`gcc`, `clang`) probably do the nice thing and give you a sane result even though it's UB.

Comment: @Lundin storing arbitrary values in a `char` object does _not_ invoke undefined behavior, see 6.2.5p3 in n1570.pdf.

Comment: @RolandIllig I already answered this in a previous comment. You cannot store values that don't fit, period.

Comment: Ah right, in the specific case of assignment/lvalue conversion it is not necessarily UB but impl.defined behavior. The relevant part would be 6.3.1.3/3 "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised." Regardless, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes most people are wrong. I think that's so here. Having said that there's nothing to stop an standard library implementor defining the behaviour that most people expect. So maybe that's why most people don't care, since they've never actually seen a bug resulting from this error.

Comment: How is his corrected version correct? casting the negative value to unsigned char won't yield anything meaningful!

Comment: why not? If I have the character ä in latin1 (iso-8859-1), it is expressed as 228. If my char is signed, ist is stored as -28. If I cast it to unsigned, it will be 228 again.

Comment: Negative value to unsigned char is well defined. The original conversion of an integer >= 128 to signed char is UB however. But not many people care about that. Nevertheless I've edited my post.

Comment: @john: Conversion from `int` to `char` is not UB, it just yields an implementation defined value when the source value is not in the range representable as a `char`.

Comment: @john: Why did you edit out the last sentence of your original answer? Was there something wrong with it?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: You're correct of course. Post edited again. This stuff is very tedious, everyone knows what will actually happen, it's a shame that the standard doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: Of couse, any implementation where the conversion from a `char` with a negative value to an `unsigned char` doesn't yield an `unsigned char` value that represents the same character as the original `char` is clearly nuts.

Comment: @glgl if we talk in terms of cross platform program, it is stored only as -28 for a twos complement representation. To be portable, you need to say `*(unsigned char*)&s[index]` so that whatever the negative value is, that you end up as 228 based on only the bitpattern.

Comment: Any implementation where plain `char` is signed and not twos-complement is nonsense. There are a LOT of issues like "negative zero" existing but not being a string terminator, and copying bytes as an array of `char` becoming a lossy operation. The spec is rather hazy on these issues, so it would just be really ill-advised to make such an implementation.

Comment: @R..: More generally, the idea of a sign-magnitude or two's-complement implementation where the largest integer type exceeded the size of a machine word is rather dubious, since multi-precision arithmetic is only practical on hardware which can handle two's-complement math without difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

The history behind the `char` type is that it was originally the type used to describe 7-bit ASCII characters. At the same time, C lacked a separate 8 bit integer type. So in the pre-standard days of the eighties, some compilers made `char` unsigned - since it doesn't make sense to have negative indices in a symbol table, while other compilers made `char` signed, to make it consistent with all the other integer types.

When the time came to standardize C, both versions existed. Unfortunately, the committee decided to let it remain that way, leaving the decision to the compiler. Instead they added two other types: `signed char` and `unsigned char`. `signed char` is part of the signed integer types, `unsigned char` is part of the unsigned integer types, and `char` is part of neither, though it must have the same representation as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`. (This is all described in C11 6.2.5)

Notably, `char` never was anything but 8 bits on all known implementations, save from some exotic oddball DSPs that worked with 16 bit bytes. When "extended" symbol tables were used, either the implementation changed from 7 to 8 bit characters, or `wchar_t` was used. Please note that `wchar_t` has been in the C language since the beginning, so assuming that `char` was at some point used for things like UTF8 is probably incorrect (though theoretically possible).

Now if `char` is signed, and you store a value larger than `CHAR_MAX` or smaller than `CHAR_MIN` inside it, you invoke undefined behavior, as per C11 6.5 §5. Period. So if you have an array of `char` and any item inside it violate the type boundaries, you have undefined behavior there already. Even though character types have to trap representations, undefined behavior could cause the code to misbehave in other ways, such as incorrect optimizations.

The ctype.h functions allow `EOF` as parameter, but should otherwise behave as if working with character types, even though the parameter is `int` to allow `EOF`. **The text from 7.4 §1 is mostly saying that "if you pass some random `int` to this function, which is neither of the same representation as a char, nor EOF, the behavior is undefined"**.

But if you pass a `char` where you have already invoked signed integer overflow/underflow, you already have undefined behavior even before calling the function - this has nothing to do with the ctype.h functions or any other function. Thus your assumption that the posted "upper" function is unsafe is incorrect - this code is no different from any other code using the `char` type.

An example of undefined behavior caused by the cited ctype.h restrictions in 7.4 would rather be something like `toupper(666)`.

Comment: C11 6.2.5p3 seems to allow saving arbitrary "characters" in an object of either character type, which would contradict the undefined behavior of 6.5p5.

Comment: In your quote of 7.4p1, it should be "unsigned char" instead of "char". On a platform where `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and `char` is signed, calling `toupper(192)` does NOT invoke undefined behavior. (Your quote suggests otherwise.)

Comment: @RolandIllig No, 6.2.5p3 points at the _basic execution character set_ which is a formal term defined in 5.2.1. Roughly meaning the English alphabet in upper and lower case, plus digits and punctuation characters etc. Which in turn roughly means 7 bit ASCII - at any rate the basic execution character set can fit in 7 bits. Beyond that, it says that other characters may be stored in an implementation-defined way "**but shall be within the range
of values that can be represented in that type**". Meaning you are still not allowed to overflow/underflow.

Comment: @RolandIllig Regarding 7.4, I didn't quote it. Yes, `toupper(192)` is fine, I have not said otherwise. But `char ch=192;` is potentially undefined behavior, no matter if you pass the char to a function or not. The whole point of this answer is to point out that there are only two problems here: 1) overflowing/underflowing a char or any other signed integer is UB. 2) passing some random garbage value to the ctype.h functions is UB. The code in your question does neither, so it is perfectly fine and safe.

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: "Now if `char` is signed, and you store a value larger than `CHAR_MAX` or smaller than `CHAR_MIN` inside it, you invoke undefined behavior, as per C11 6.5 §5. Period." -- I disagree with this statement. The relevant part of the standard in this case is [§6.3.1.3 ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3), which states that the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. In your comment to one of the other answers, you pointed this out yourself, but it seems that you didn't update your own answer afterwards.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel The part you quote applies when conversions take place. But you can store a value in a variable without invoking conversions. For example through lvalue access: `*(unsigned char*)pointer_to_char = CHAR_MAX+1;`. This is for example what happens if you write the the wrong conversion specifier to `scanf`.