# trouble trimming a string in c

Tags: c, string, trim

I am using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way) as a guide to trimming a string in C.  It works properly on a string bounded exclusively by whitespaces (`' '`), but on special whitespaces (`'\r'`, `'\n'`,  `'\t'`, etc.), it fails.  Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t trim(char *out, size_t len, const char *str)
{
  if(len == 0)
    return 0;

  const char *end;
  size_t out_size;

  // Trim leading space
  while(isspace(*str)) str++;

  if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
  {
    *out = 0;
    return 1;
  }

  // Trim trailing space
  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;
  end++;

  // Set output size to minimum of trimmed string length and buffer size minus 1
  out_size = (end - str) < len-1 ? (end - str) : len-1;

  // Copy trimmed string and add null terminator
  memcpy(out, str, out_size);
  out[out_size] = 0;

  return out_size;
}

int main(){

    char *str = " \n\n  hello  \t    \r  ";
    char trimmed[strlen(str)];

    trim (trimmed, strlen(trimmed), str);
    printf("~%s~\n~%s~\n", str, trimmed);

    return 0;
}
```

produces the output:

```
~ 

  ~ello         
~~
```

can anyone fix the code to trim all whitespace characters properly?

Second Question:  The first function in the referenced answer gives me a segfault.  does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you called the function is incorrect.

```
char *str = " \n\n  hello  \t    \r  ";
char trimmed[strlen(str)+1]; // Note that you must +1 for the terminating \0.

// Use sizeof() instead of strlen() because trimmed is containing garbage.
// strlen() measures the length of the content while sizeof() measure the allocated size of the array.
trim (trimmed, sizeof(trimmed), str);
```

Answer (score 0):

try isgraph instead of/in addition to isspace

Answer (score -1):

> but on special whitespaces ('\r', '\n', '\t', etc.), it fails.

In C, characters are `unsigned integers`, so if you say `white-space`, one would understand `' '`, whose ASCII code is 32 in decimal or 0x20 in HEX. Characters you mentioned **are not** white spaces!

`' ' != '\r'`

Below is my implementation for `trim`, `left-trim`, and `right-trim` functions to remove surrounding (i.e. leading and trailing), leading and trailing white-spaces from a chracter string, respectively. Functions require no extra header, the most possible bare-bone implementation that relies on integers and pointer arithmetics only.

You can modify the code (in your case, you need to expand logical `if` cases to cover other characters, such as `\r`, `\n`, `\t`, etc., you mentioned in your post) according to your needs.

I will add these functions to [my string library, zString](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString) :)

```
char *zstring_trim(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    int in_word=0;  /* logical check */
    int index=0;    /* index of the last non-space char*/

    while (*src)
        if(*src!=' '){
         /* Found a word */
            in_word = 1;
            *dst++ = *src++;  /* make the assignment first
                               * then increment
                               */
        } else if (*src==' ' && in_word==0) {
         /* Already going through a series of white-spaces */
            in_word=0;
            ++src;
        } else if (*src==' ' && in_word==1) {
         /* End of a word, dont mind copy white spaces here */
            in_word=0;
            *dst++ = *src++;
            index = (dst-str)-1; /* location of the last char */
        }

    /* terminate the string */
    *(str+index)='\0';

    return str;
}

char *zstring_ltrim(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    int index=0;    /* index of the first non-space char */

    /* skip leading white-spaces */
    for(; *src && *src==' '; ++src, ++index)
        ;

    /* copy rest of the string */
    while(*src)
        *dst++ = *src++;

    /* terminate the string */
    *(src-index)='\0';

    return str;
}

char *zstring_rtrim(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    int index=0;    /* index of the last non-space char*/

    /* copy the string */
    while(*src){
        *dst++ = *src++;
        if (*src!=' ' && *src)
            index = (src-str)+1;
    }

    /* terminate the string */
    *(str+index)='\0';

    return str;
}
```

Comment: The person who **down voted** the post had a bit of C knowledge or patience to read the code, he should have noticed that all three functions work only for white-space (ASCII code 32 decimal), not for `\r`,`\n`, or `\t`! It is just a matter of amending `if` conditions, or a better approach could be updating function prototypes to accept desired `space character to remove`, such as `char *zstring_trim(char *str, const char space)`.