# how do I delete just the first space in string? Language C

Tags: c, string

how do I delete just the first spaces or tabs in string?

```
char* DelFistSpace(char* s){
    int i,k=1;
    char * out=s;
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++)
        if((s[i]!=' ' && s[i]!='    ')  || k==0){
            out[i]=s[i];
            k=0;
        }
        out[i]='\0';
        puts(out);
        return out;
}
```

For example: `DelFistSpace("(space)(space)(space)a a");`

expected: `"a a"`

Comment: The dupe-linked question has such good-quality answers, it's better to try and adapt those than get another one for this special case here, in my opinion.

Comment: @unwind Just went through answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way.  Sadly, at least 2 have potential UB dealing with trimming at the end.  Maybe use `int` when `size_t` or `ssize_t` would be better.  Even the accepted one fails using memcpy when memmove should be used for potential overlapping source and destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming client code will keep track of the original pointer if it needs to delete dynamically allocated memory, you could simply use

```
char* SkipLeadingSpaces(char* s){
    while (isspace(*s)) {
        s++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

If you want to keep using the original pointer in client code, just without the leading spaces, you could try something like

```
void RemoveLeadingSpaces(char* s){
    int trim = 0;
    char* trimmed = s;
    while (isspace(*s)) {
        s++;
    }
    for (; *s; s++) {
        *trimmed++ = *s;
    }
    *trimmed = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Even better use `isspace` rather than the explicit character tests.

Comment: Do not forget *s && (...) in your while. What if the string has no blanks?

Comment: @Eregrith That isn't needed. When it reaches the end of the string the current `while` condition will be false and it will stop.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks, I've updated to do this

Comment: ***[isspace()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/)***  also tests for `\t'  ( _while (isspace(*s) || *s == '\t') {_ )

Comment: @ryyker Yep, I just beat you to that update :-)

Comment: referring to the first example too :), no biggie.

Comment: @interjay ah yes, I read the condition wrong >_<

Comment: @chux Thanks, that certainly wasn't intended.  Now corrected.

Comment: @simonc Some _small_ ideas:  `int trim = 0;` is not used.  `for (; *s; s++) { *trimmed++ = *s; } *trimmed = '\0';` could be replaced with `do { *trimmed++ = *s; } while (*s++);`.  But your answer is correct anyways.