# Deleting whitespace up to first valid character C

Tags: c, arrays, char, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I basically have want to remove all the leading whitespace before the first valid character in an array.

For example if I have something like `'    1.6, 1.7'`, I want it to be `'1.6, 1.7'` or if it was just `'1.7, 1.8'`, then it would be `'1.7, 1.8'`

This is my method for the whitespace, however it only shows where the whitespace are. I need help removing it.

```
char **storeArray

void Students::removeSpace()
{
   int MAX_SIZE = 30;
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
     for(int j=0; j<MAX_SIZE; j++)
     {
        if(isspace(storeArray[i][j]) && !(isspace(storeArray[i][j++])
        {
          // I NEED HELP HERE. I'M TRYING TO REMOVE ALL THE LEADING WHITESPACE ONLY
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Basically loop and count how many leading spaces there are, and then shift the whole array left by that value.

Comment: Students::removeSpace() looks more like C++ than C.  What's the definition of storeArray ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trim leading/trailing whitespace in a standard way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way)

Comment: Btw. you only remove whitespaces that are followed by non whilespaces.  '  xx' would result in ' xx' and not 'xx'.

Comment: Beware of (absence of) side effects to `i` in `(isspace(storeArray[i]) && !(isspace(storeArray[i++]))`

Comment: @RPGillespie, how do I loop if there are whitespace after the leading character?

Comment: You mean like this?: `while(isspace(*source++));while((*dest++=*source++));`  It's helpful to learn pointers.

Answer (score 2):

To remove extra white-space, march through the string:

```
void Remove_Leading_ExtraMiddle_Trailing_Whitespace(char *s, int size) {
  char *end = &s[size];
  char *t = s;
  // skip leading
  while (isspace(*s))
    s++;

  // middle
  for (;;) {
    while (!isspace(*s) && *s != '\0') {
      *t++ = *s++;
    }
    if (*s == '\0')
      break;
    *t = *s++;
    while (isspace(*s))
      s++;
    if (*s == '\0') {
      break;
    }
    t++;
  }

  // end
  while (t < end) {
    *t++ = '\0';
  }
}

void removeSpace() {
  int MAX_SIZE = 30;
  char storeArray[4][MAX_SIZE];
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Remove_Leading_ExtraMiddle_Trailing_Whitespace(storeArray[i], MAX_SIZE);
  }
}
```

Comment: I like it. If the strings are actual strings, only thing I'd do different is have the remove function calculate the length and dispense with the need to send the size.

Comment: @David C. Rankin  Agree, but OP seems to want to work with array of `char` rather than C string.  IAC OP's post looks C++ like yet with C tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char storeArray[20] = "   Check it out.";
    int whitespace = 0;

    printf("%s\n", storeArray);

    //Count leading whitespace
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        if(storeArray[i] == ' ' || storeArray[i] == '\t')
            whitespace++;
        else
            break;
    }

    //Shift everything left
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        if (i+whitespace < 20)
            storeArray[i] = storeArray[i+whitespace];
        else
            storeArray[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("%s\n", storeArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't the end result be `Checkitout.`? Because you are removing all whitespace

Comment: Nope, compile it yourself and see. This code only gets rid of the leading whitespace. The code `break`s after encountering the first non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the c-strings are not longer than MAX_SIZE and if they are null terminated strings:

```
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
     int j=0; 
     while (j<MAX_SIZE && isspace(storeArray[i][j]) 
         j++;
     if (j==MAX_SIZE)  // oops ! Not null terminated and only whitespace ? 
         storeArray[i][0]='\0';
     else if (j>0) // if no leading whiespace do nothing !
         strcpy (storeArray[i], &storeArray[i][j]);    // if you like c style
   }
```

If you are working in C++ (as the `Student::removeSpace()` suggest), and if you really don't want to work with `std::string`, then you could consider replace all this with:

```
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
       copy(find_if(storeArray[i], storeArray[i] + MAX_SIZE, [](char c){ return c && !isspace(c); }), storeArray[i] + MAX_SIZE, storeArray[i]);
```

***Edit:*** If you want to avoid moving your strings, and if you can afford to change the string pointers (i.e.you didn't dynamically allocate the strings), then you could do as well:

```
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
       for (int j=MAX_SIZE-1; j>=0 && isspace(*storeArray[i]); j--) 
           storeArray[i]++;  // no move or copy, but original pointer lost forever
```

Comment: Thanks, I like using c-strings and it will not be longer than `MAX_SIZE`. Thing is, how do I remove the trailing whitespace, without copying into array?

Comment: Loop through the array backwards and set the last whitespace you encounter to `'\0'`

Comment: @RPGillespie, Sorry I am not with you. Why would you set the last whitespace to `'\0'`? I'm trying to remove leading whitespace only

Comment: you should use the `memmove` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, that's a valid alternative ! You then don't have to worry about null terminator.

Comment: @SamThers You asked how to remove the "trailing whitespace" - and you do so by looping through the string backwards and after encountering the first non-whitespace character, you set the previous whitespace to `'\0'`, thus terminating the string, thus removing the trailing whitespace.

Comment: @SamThers in fact strcpy() or memmove() shift the chars to the begin of the string in the same array.  There's no way arround.  An alternative is to modify the pointer.  The problem is however that you loose the trace of your original pointer and if the string was allocated dynamically, you'll have if you have no way to free it later.

Comment: `strcpy` may work and may not work to operate properly if the memory area is overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep `strtrimws` as a separate function or incorporate its contents within your `Students::removeSpace` function. The following function can be used with or without assigning the return. Examples: `strtrimws (somestring);` or `char *newstring = strtrimws (somestring);` Also note, while the original string 's' is modified by the function, the start address for 's' is unchanged making it safe for use with dynamically allocated strings. Shown below in context with your `removeSpace` function:

```
#include <ctype.h>

/** remove leading and trailing whitespace, original not preserved.
 *  this funciton can be used with or without assigning the return.
 */
char *strtrimws (char *s)
{
    char *sp = s;                   /* start pointer to return  */
    char *p = s;                    /* pointer to parse string  */

    while (isspace (*s))  s++;      /* skip leading whitespace  */
    while (*s) *p++ = *s++;         /* reindex s to end         */
    while (isspace (*p)) *p-- = 0;  /* null-terminate from end  */

    return sp;
}

char **storeArray;

void Students::removeSpace()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        strtrimws (storeArray[i]);
}
```

**NOTE:** if you have initialized all pointers to `zero/NULL` in `storeArray` before assigning strings to (some or all) of the `pointers-to-char` you can simplify/improve `removeSpace` by eliminating the hardcoded number of iterations for `i` and replacing it with a simple:

```
void Students::removeSpace()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (storeArray[i])
        strtrimws (storeArray[i++]);
}
```

**Example of funciton in use:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/** remove leading and trailing whitespace, original not preserved.
*  this funciton can be used with or without assigning return.
*/
char *strtrimws (char *s)
{
    char *sp = s;                   /* start pointer to return  */
    char *p = s;                    /* pointer to parse string  */

    while (isspace (*s))  s++;      /* skip leading whitespace  */
    while (*s) *p++ = *s++;         /* reindex s to end         */
    while (isspace (*p)) *p-- = 0;  /* null-terminate from end  */

    return sp;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "\n error: insufficient input. Usage:  %s char* char* ... (max 5)\n\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char array[5][50] = {{0}};
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        strncpy (array[i-1], argv[i], strlen (argv[i]));
        printf ("\n array[%d] '%s'\n", i, strtrimws (array[i-1]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/stripwsarray " string 1 ws " "  string 2 ws  " "   string 3 ws   "

 array[0] 'string 1 ws'

 array[1] 'string 2 ws'

 array[2] 'string 3 ws'
```