# Issues reading from file into a correct "format" using strtok

Tags: c

I am having an issue reading in a file with a certain format using strtok.
Each line in the file contains a format as shown below:

*Bill Simpson, 01452356*

When I display only `temp_id` I get (Underscore = whitespace):

```
"_01452356"
```

The code for breaking apart each line is as follows:

```
while((fgets(temp_string, LENGTH, ifp))!= NULL)
    {
          temp_name = strtok(temp_string, comma);
          temp_id = strtok(NULL, comma);
          add(temp_name, temp_id);
    }
```

I simply want `temp_id` to not contain whitespace. 
Keep in mind that `temp_name` and `temp_id` are both arrays of type char.
I would greatly appreciate a quick solution to this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I trim leading/trailing whitespace in a standard way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicity include the `space` character as a delimiter.

```
char comma[] = ", ";
```

They could be the other way round

```
char comma[] = " ,";
```

because they are not a sequence, but a set of chars that may be delimiters.