# How to remove empty values from an array in C?

Tags: c, cgi

I have an array with some values like:

```
char s[] = {" ","a","b","c"," "};
```

How I can remove these empty values?

**Description (Collected from comment):**

I have an array that I got from a function and when i printed with `sprintf` returns me a string like this: `" foo"` two blanks or depend, this because I am replacing some characters with blank-space `(' ')` characters, but when I use the variable in another function, these spaces gives me errors because the empty values, then I need to do a "*split*" like java does, how can I do this?

Comment: This declaration/definition is wrong, enable compilation warnings, what does your compiler tell you? Also please clarify what do you mean by *remove*? It's not the way a c programmer would think! So please explain why you want to do this to provice a c ish solution. Note that "*removing*" the values would in general be unnecessary work.

Comment: I have an array that I got from a function and when i printed with sprintf returns me a string like this: "  foo" two blanks or depend, this because I am replacing some characters with blankspace (' ') characters, but when I use the variable in another function, these spaces gives me errors because the empty values, then I need to do a "split" like java does, how can I do this?

Comment: you can create another array of string and save only valid strings in that. If the string is empty, don't copy to the newer array.

Comment: @user3295036  Over-write your original array . Using a  function or using loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way take a look at this question. If u want to split the string u can use strtok function in C.

Comment: OP, create your own answer and accept it.  Do not put your answer in the post

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about "deleting them", but you can count the everything except for the "blank spaces", and create an array of that size and transfer all the "non-blank spaces".

Something like this maybe? This may not be the best answer out there, this is just for demonstration purposes.

I don't know if you will have an end of line character in your char array... so this is another way of doing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count (char s[5]){
    int count = 0, i;
    for(i=0; i<5;i++){
        if(s[i]!=' ')count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void load(int size, char s[size], char s1[5]){
    int i, j=0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    if( s1[i]!=' '){s[j]=s1[i];
    j++;}
    }
}

int main(){

char s[5] = {' ','a','b','c',' '};
int size = count(s);
char newS[size];
load(size, newS, s);
puts(newS);

return 1;}
```

Comment: Ok this works fine, but the size remains the same as the other array, i need to pass it to the new array with the new size of valid values, therefore I said how I can 'remove' those values

Comment: @user3295036 The function counts the valid char values in the string... Then returns that value to make an array of that size, so, no the new array has a different size (in the case above, it would be of size 3 instead of size 5).