# Building compiler - How to check if char array is empty (using fgets)

Tags: c

I'm building an assembly compiler in C, and I need to print only line which contain code (alphanumeric characters).
However my compiler doesn't recognize a string pointed to by `fgets()` as empty, since it sometimes contains **whitespace characters**.

How do I make a condition, to only print lines containing alphanumeric characters?

My code looks like this:

```
while(fgets(Line,256,Inputfile)!=NULL)
{   
    i=0;

    while(Line[i]!='\n')
    {               
        Instruction[i]=Line[i]; 
        i++;    
    }

        printf("%s \n",Instruction);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Use **while( ! isspace( *strptr++) )** somewhere.

Comment: This question could be made much more simple by throwing out any reference to building a compiler, assembler, etc. Those details have nothing at all to do with the problem at hand, and extra details only make communications more difficult.

Comment: The fact that you are building a compiler (or assembler?) is irrelevant, so the tag was removed.  This is just a basic C I/O and string question.  The function `strcspn` probably does what you want if you *only* want to ignore lines with whitespace.

Comment: Apologies for referencing compiler - I am relatively new to this website an I assumed I should give a little context of my problem. Thank you for your understanding. Will remember for next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to *trim* the result of the fgets. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way) to view an example that shows how to trim an array of characters in C.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you right? You want to ignore lines with only whitespaces?

```
while(fgets(Line,256,Inputfile)!=NULL)
{   
   i=0;
   int flag = 0;
   while(Line[i]!='\n')
   {               
      if(Line[i] != ' ' && Line[i] != '\t'){
         flag = 1;
      }
      Instruction[i]=Line[i]; 
      i++;    
   }
    if(flag == 1){
       printf("%s \n",Instruction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this - that's exactly what I was trying to do!
BTW, what is `'\t'` ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a function `isLineToIgnore()` in which you check whether the line contains any alphanumeric characters or not.

```
int isLineToIgnore(char* line)
{
   for (char* cp = line; *cp != '\0'; ++cp )
   {
      if ( isalnum(*cp) )
      {
         // Don't ignore the line if it has at least one
         // alphanumeric character
         return 0;
      }
   }

   // The line has no alphanumeric characters.
   // Ignore it.
   return 1;
}
```

and then call the function.