# Set Char* to Trim of Char in C

Tags: c, pointers, trim, calloc

Lets see this example:

```
char var1[100] = "test    ";
char* var2;
```

If I do this:

```
var2 = &var1;
```

I'll get it with spaces.

I want var2 to be the trim of var1.

Comment: did you try anything? I suggest `strchr(var1, ' ')` as a good place to start

Comment: `char var1 = "test       ";` is not a valid initialization. You are attempting to assign an address (typically 4 or 8 bytes) value into a character (typically 1 byte) variable.

Comment: Bad initialization right. Corrected.

Comment: alternatively you can use a search engine , looking for 'c string trim' finds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way

Comment: Still not valid. This code shouldn't even compile!!!

Comment: barak manos not its right. It was that way to make myself understood easily. sorry

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way of doing this without changing the original string or copying a modified version of that string to a new source.

As pm100 said, you can find the pointer pointing to the first instance of space in that string, then get the distance from your source pointer and that pointer to find the index of the whitespace. After doing so, simply use `strncpy` to copy that portion of the string to a new pointer. Make sure you allocate your new pointer **and** put the terminating character '\0' at the end.

The other solution is to simply use strchr again as pm100 said, but this time change what that pointer points to to '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

a quicky

```
var2 = strdup(var1);
char * idx = strchr(var2, ' ');
if(idx) *idx = 0;
```