# Remove Trailing Spaces in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to remove trailing spaces however I keep getting a segmentation fault. Not too sure where I am accessing memory out of bounds but this is my code. Leading spaces works fine.

String is the input for the function.

```
//remove leading spaces
char* final = string;
while(isspace((unsigned char)final[0]))
        final++;

 //removing trailing spaces
//getting segmentation fault here
    int length = strlen(final);
    while(length > 0 && isspace((unsigned char)final[length-1]))
            length--;
    final[length-1] = '\0';
```

The string I tested was

```
char* word = "  1 2 Hello    ";
printf("%s\n", removeSpaces(word));
```

When I comment out the trailing spaces, it works perfectly. I don't why the code is failing at the trailing spaces. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trim leading/trailing whitespace in a standard way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way)

Comment: Your `word` points to a **readonly** array of char. You cannot change them, you need to make a copy into writable memory. To help themselves some people use `const char *word = "  1 2 hello    ";`

Comment: Oops... I meant it works for leading spaces. Thx @chux

Comment: It works for leading spaces because you just increase the pointer, you don't change the contents of the (**readonly**) array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string literal `"  1 2 Hello    "` is stored in read-only memory. Copy it first before attempting to write '\0' into it, and the problem will go away. So e.g., just replace this:

```
char* final = string;
```

with this:

```
char* final = strdup(string);
```

Edit 1: Upon considering this in more detail, I realized you also do a leading trim before trailing trim. Since you are moving the pointer, the allocation needs to happen **after** the leading trim, or the caller will not be able to free the memory. Here's a complete solution that shouldn't have any errors:

```
char *removeSpaces(const char *string) {

    while(isspace((unsigned char)string[0]))
        string++;
    char *final = strdup(string);
    int length = strlen(final);
    while(length > 0 && isspace((unsigned char)final[length-1]))
        length--;
    final[length-1] = '\0';
    return final;
}
```

Edit 2: While I would not recommend it in this case, it might be useful to be aware that if the variable was declared like this:

```
char word[] = "  1 2 Hello    ";
```

It would have been in writable memory, and the problem would also not exist. Thanks to [pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg) for the idea.

The reason why it is not a good approach is that you are expecting the callers to the function to always provide writable strings, and that you will modify them. A function that returns a duplicate is a much better approach in general.

(Don't forget to free() the result afterwards!)

Comment: Or use an array rather than a pointer: `char word[] = " 1 2 hello ";`

Comment: I would wager that since OP has this as a function, it will be called from various other places. The function should really return a duplicate and be documented with the fact that the caller is responsible for freeing.

Comment: @pmg But yes, for a newbie, it is useful to know that that is also a possibility. I will amend my answer - thanks for the idea.

Comment: 1) `final[length-1] = '\0';` is bad (UB) when `length == 0`.  2) `strlen(final)` returns a `size_t`.   Better to use that here than`int length`.

Comment: I didn't declare the array like word[] is because my input will not be in that form.

Comment: @treatyoself,  array and pointer are interchangeable in this context. you can assign a char[] to a char*. The difference is that if you assign the string literal to a pointer at initialization, you are literally pointing to the string literal (read-only memory on most OSes today, and usually shared between all instances of the same text content in the program); and if you assign to an array at initialization, then the compiler generates code that fills a new array (on the stack if it's local like here) with that content.

Comment: Thank you all for helping out!