# Remove a Space from a Specific case in a string

Tags: c, trim, c-strings

I made a simple program that remove all spaces from a string but i want is a program to remove space from **the start of a string** if there is and another program to remove space from **the end of a string**

Hope this make sense

Here is my c program that remove spaces from all the string giving

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int i,j=0;
    char str[50];
    printf("Donnez une chaine: ");
    gets(str);

    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';++i)
    {
        if(str[i]!=' ')
            str[j++]=str[i];
    }

    str[j]='\0';
    printf("\nSans Espace: %s",str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its i c and its not a duplicate because that one is not simple i just want a simple one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trim leading/trailing whitespace in a standard way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way)

Comment: It seems you did the most difficult... For start: skip spaces and then copy as you did for any chars. For end: from the end, skip spaces and set a \0 on the last one.

Comment: Sorry but  i don't understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below approach

1. First removes the leading white chars.
2. Then shift the string.
3. Then removes the trailing white chars.

   ```
    char *beg = str;
    char *travel = str;

    /*After while loop travel will point to non whitespace char*/
     while(*travel == ' ') travel++;

   /*Removes the leading white spaces by shifting chars*/
    while(*beg = *travel){
        beg++;
        travel++;
    }

   /* travel will be pointing to \0 char*/
    if(travel != str) {
      travel--;
      beg--;
    }

   /*Remove the trailing white chars*/
    while(*travel == ' ' && travel != beg) travel--;

   /*Mark the end of the string*/
   if(travel != str) *(travel+1) = '\0';
   ```

Comment: Im really sorry but i still don't understant could you write it in a exemple code where the user give a string and it remove spaces from the end and the lead so i could understant ?

Comment: `/* travel will be pointing to \0 char*/` Since you are using a post increment in the while loop, wouldn't `travel` point to the `char` after `'\0'`? (Also it can not be the same as `str` because it is at least incremented once)

Comment: @fairy remove your code between `gets(str);` and  `printf("\nSans Espace: %s",str);` insert my code. Also you should not be using `gets` you should use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @fairy Please read the documentations and man pages, this is no place to explain common standard functions.