# c, trimming strings, and wide characters

Tags: c, trim, widechar, widestring

Briefly, I'm parsing HTTP headers, received from libcurl, in an environment where I need wide characters. The headers arrive to me as char * strings, in the general format

`name: value`

I'm separating this into two strings by writing a null into the position of the colon, and then trimming:

```c
        int offset = index_of( ':', s );

        if ( offset != -1 ) {
            s[offset] = ( char ) 0;
            char *name = trim( s );
            char *value = trim( &s[++offset] );
```

The trim function I'm using is one I wrote myself:

```c
char *trim( char *s ) {
    int i;

    for ( i = strlen( s ); ( isblank( s[i] ) || iscntrl( s[i] ) ) && i >= 0;
          i-- ) {
        s[i] = '\0';
    }
    for ( i = 0; ( isblank( s[i] ) || iscntrl( s[i] ) ) && s[i] != '\0'; i++ );

    return ( char * ) &s[i];
}
```

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way) and have tried the trim functions recommended by it, but they didn't solve my problem so for the time being I've gone back to my own.

I then feed the trimmed strings to the `mbstowcs` function:

```c
struct cons_pointer add_meta_string( struct cons_pointer meta, wchar_t *key,
                                     char *value ) {
    wchar_t buffer[strlen( value ) + 1];
    /* \todo something goes wrong here: I sometimes get junk characters on the
     * end of the string. */
    mbstowcs( buffer, value, strlen( value ) );
    return make_cons( make_cons( c_string_to_lisp_keyword( key ),
                                 c_string_to_lisp_string( buffer ) ), meta );
}
```

The junk character I get seems always to be the same one:

```lisp
:: (inspect (assoc :owner (meta l)))

    STRG (1196577875) at page 7, offset 797 count 2
        String cell: character 's' (115) next at page 7 offset 798, count 2
         value: "simon翾"
"simon翾"
:: (inspect (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (assoc :owner (meta l)))))))))

    STRG (1196577875) at page 7, offset 802 count 2
        String cell: character '翾' (32766) next at page 0 offset 0, count 2
         value: "翾"
```

32766 [is the highest signed 16-bit number](https://css-tricks.com/32766/), -1, which is probably significant; and implies to me that `mbstowcs` is reading off the end of the string, which implies in turn that strlen may be returning a spurious value.

I am able to read wide characters from the stream:

```lisp
:: (assoc :x-lambda (meta l))

"λάμβδα"
```

I am by no means a C expert; this is the first significant C project I've done in almost 30 years, so I may be missing something very obvious; and help greatly appreciated. Full source code, if you're interested, is [here](https://github.com/simon-brooke/post-scarcity/blob/develop/src/io/io.c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off by 1

`mbstowcs()` converts arrays.  If the result is to also include a *null character*, account fo that in the length passed to the function.

```
// mbstowcs( buffer, value, strlen( value ) );
mbstowcs( buffer, value, strlen( value ) + 1);
```

Lack of a *null character* in `buffer` is likely messing up the following `make_cons()`.

---

Other

`for ( i = strlen( s ); ( isblank( s[i] ) || iscntrl( s[i] ) ) && i >= 0; i-- )` . is broken. Do `i >= 0` test before `s[i]`.

Note `is...(int ch)` expects `ch` in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`. This code is UB when `s[i] < 0`. Usual fix: `is...((unsigned char) s[i])`.

Comment: And just to confirm, your solution worked. Thanks again.