# Splitting string with colons and spaces?

Tags: c++, arduino

So I've made my code work for separating the string:

```
    String c;
 
    for (int j = 0 ; j < count; j++) {
        c += ip(ex[j]);
    }
  
    return c;                      
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

I have had no luck with this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply add a delimiter to your tokenizer. From a [strtok() description](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) the second parameter "is the C string containing the delimiters. These may vary from one call to another".

So add a 'space' delimiter to your tokenization: `ex[i] = strtok(NULL, ": ");` [trim any whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way) from your tokens, and throw away any empty tokens. The last two shouldn't be necessary, because the delimiters won't be part of your collected tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `<regex>` library if the compiler of yours supports C++11.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

const std::regex ws_re(":| +");
void printTokens(const std::string& input)
{
    std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), ws_re, -1),
               std::sregex_token_iterator(),
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}

int main()
{
    const std::string text1 = "...:---:...";
    std::cout<<"no whitespace:\n";
    printTokens(text1);

    std::cout<<"single whitespace:\n";
    const std::string text2 = "..:---:... ..:---:...";
    printTokens(text2);

    std::cout<<"multiple whitespaces:\n";
    const std::string text3 = "..:---:...   ..:---:...";
    printTokens(text3);
}
```

The description of library is on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). If you are not familiar with regular expressions, the part in the code above `const std::regex ws_re(":| +");` means that there should be either ':' symbol or (`or` in regular expressions denoted by pipe symbol '|') any amount of whitespaces ('+' stands for 'one or more symbol that stands before the plus sign'). Then one is able to use this regular expression to tokenize any input with `std::sregex_token_iterator`. For more complex cases than whitespaces, there is wonderful [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).
The only disadvantage I could think of is that regex engine is likely to be slower than simple handwritten tokenizer.

Comment: Thank you for your input but this doesn't work on arduino IDE.

Comment: What is the error?