# array/string not being returned, function returns null, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c

```
char stripper(char x[]){
    char stripped[20];
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(x);i++){
        if(x[i]==' '){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            stripped[c]=x[i];
            c++;
        }
    }
    return stripped;
}
```

this is the function i've created to return a string/sentence without whitespaces. using this function as a void function and simply printing the `stripped` string works, but this iteration of the code returns `(null)`. i am somewhat of a newbie to C so simple solutions to solve this problem would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `char* stripper(char x[])`? You've defined the function to return a `char`. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/q/122616/2970947

Comment: You can't return a local array from a function.

Comment: You also shouldn't be calling `strlen` on each end every iteration of the loop (unless you want it to run vastly slower).   Take the length *once*, before entering the loop.  It's just common sense.